# Change legend in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have plotted ten lines in a single graph and I use `color=Var2` to let ggplot2 automatically assign a color to each line. Now I would like to change the legend to something like "A1, A2, A3, A4" instead of "2.5, 5, 7.5, 10". Could anyone teach me how to accomplish this?

Attached is the image:

[image]

The data looks like:

[image]

```
abc <- melt(prop_combined)
ggplot(data = abc, aes(x = Var1, y = value, group = Var2, color = Var2)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() +
  labs(color='NEW LEGEND TITLE')
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data using `dput(abc)` so we can recreate your plot?

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data and consider using `color = factor (Var2)`

Comment: Create a column in your data that has the labels you want to use instead of numeric values. Use `color = that_column` instead of `color = Var2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
ggplot(data = abc, aes(x = Var1, y = value, group = Var2, color = Var2)) + 
 geom_line() + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_gradient(limits = c(0, 10), 
                        breaks = c(0, 2.5, 5, 7.5, 10),
                        labels = c("A0", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"))
```